# É verdade (ainda?) que cada roteador do Tor mantém uma conexão com cada outro roteador? Por quê?

Tags: segurança, redes, tor

O [artigo original](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a465464.pdf) descrevendo o [projeto Tor](https://torproject.org/), no primeiro parágrafo da seção 4, diz:

> Cada roteador cebola (*onion router*) mantém uma conexão TLS com cada outro roteador cebola.

O paper é de dez anos atrás (2004), quando havia um número muito menor de relays na rede Tor. [Hoje existem mais de 5000](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html).

- Esse número não estoura algum limite de sockets abertos ou algo assim?
- Não impõe uma penalidade de desempenho sobre os relays?
- Manter ou não essas conexões afeta alguma primitiva de segurança?
- E que tipo de mensagens eles trocam nessas conexões abertas quando não fazem parte de um mesmo circuito?

P.S.: desculpa se a tradução "roteador cebola" dá arrepios em alguém. Acho jocosa ;)

Comment: Cross-postei no tor.SE: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/is-is-still-true-that-each-onion-relay-keeps-an-open-tls-connection-to-every-oth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O fato de cada nó do tipo "Relay" ter que se conectar a qualquer outro nó desse mesmo tipo não significa que as conexões *precisam* ficar abertas 100% do tempo - só enquanto estão sendo usadas. Não conheço o protocolo em detalhes, mas segundo [esse thread](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2013-April/002046.html) num dado momento apenas um subconjunto das conexões possíveis estão de fato abertas. Há um limite configurável para o número máximo de sockets abertos simultaneamente, por essa razão.

Não sei falar sobre o desempenho, mas a segurança da rede é sim impactada pelo número de nós. Segundo essas [duas](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/41542/6939) [perguntas](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/49071/6939) no security.SE, se um atacante (por exemplo a NSA) criar um grande número de Relays, e uma conexão **iniciar e terminar** num Relay controlado por eles (ainda que saia e entre de novo) é possível correlacionar o tamanho do pacote e a data/hora da conexão, e assim concluir que o endereço de IP "A" se comunicou com o "B" - e em muitos casos (ou todos), conhecer também o conteúdo dessa comunicação.

Se a conexão somente se inicia num nó controlado pelo atacante, não dá pra saber o conteúdo, apenas fazer um perfil (i.e. saber que o IP "A" usa Tor) - o que dependendo do país e seu regime pode ser tudo o que precisam saber.

Se há defesa para isso ou não, não sei dizer, há muita informação e eu realmente não estou familiarizado com esse protocolo. O que eu sei é que existem diversos tipos de nós: `Entry`/`Exit`, que se comunicam com os clientes Tor; `Relay`, que se comunicam uns com os outros, e podem ou não ser também Entry/Exit; `Bridge`, que não é listado no diretório Tor, de modo a tornar difícil identificar e bloquer todos os nós; etc. Em algumas circunstâncias, um cliente pode ser configurado para restringir quais nós podem ser usados como Entry, mas [de acordo com o FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit) isso normalmente não deve ser feito, podendo inclusive piorar o anonimato.

Quanto à última pergunta, não creio que haja qualquer comunicação entre os nós quando eles não estão participando de um circuito naquele momento (i.e. transmitindo um pacote do ponto A pro B). Tanto é que os soquetes podem ser fechados - se não o são, é por razões de eficiência.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Quanto à pergunta principal, de fato, procurei agora e vi que existe a opção `ConstrainedSockSize` (https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en). Obrigado pelo esclarecimento! Sobre a segurança, me referia ao fato de ter ou não as conexões abertas. Realmente, o número de nós é fundamental à anonimidade, mas não sabia se essas conexões precisavam ficar abertas por algum motivo. Obrigado pela ajuda!